SQLAlchemy - Delete model classes
I'm dynamically creating model classes in my unit tests using pytest, like so:
from sqlalchemy import Column

...

obj_args = {
    "__tablename__": f"t_{name}",
    "__table_args__": {"extend_existing": True},
    "id": Column(Integer, primary_key=True),
}

obj_args.update({col: Column(String) for col in cols})

obj = type(name, (BaseModelDerivedFromDeclarativeBase,), obj_args)

Those objects keep existing after the unit test, leaving me with side effects for other unit tests (e.g. when I recreate a model class with the same name).
Is it possible to remove those model classes from SQLAlchemy completely after each test?

You can use clear_mappers(), or create a new base model for each test.
